# How to gunzip without overwriting non-interactively

Tags: bash, gunzip

I want to unzip `.gz` files but without overwriting. When the resulting file exists, gunzip will ask for permission to overwrite, but I want gunzip not to overwrite by default and just abort. I read in a man that `-f` force overwriting, but I haven't found nothing about skipping it.

```
gunzip ${file}
```

I need something like `-n` in copying `cp -n ${file}`

Comment: your question is not very clear. By default gunzip will not overwrite existing files.

Comment: by default it is asking if overwrite or not

Comment: okay, so you want non-interactive gunzip that does not overwrite?

Comment: if so, the answer of konsolebox will do just fine... and you can accept it if it does what you want. If not, please make your question more clear

Comment: yes his answer is ok, but I have to wait 5 min to accept it ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Granting your files have `.gz` extensions, you can check if the file exists before running `gunzip`:

```
[[ -e ${file%.gz} ]] || gunzip "${file}"
```

[[ -e `${file%.gz}` ]] removes `.gz` and checks if a file having its name exists. If not (false), `||` would run `gunzip "${file}"`.

Answer (score 27):

`gunzip` will prompt you before overwriting a file. You can use the `yes` command to automatically send an `n` string to the `gunzip` prompt, as shown below:

```
$ yes n | gunzip file*.gz
gunzip: file already exists;    not overwritten
gunzip: file2 already exists;    not overwritten
```

Comment: how do I send a `y` to overwrite without a prompt?

Comment: This causes a broken pipe

Comment: @seralouk, as the the manual, you can use the --force flag: gunzip -f file*.gz

Answer (score 3):

Here's a combination of the answers here and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/139419/how-do-i-gunzip-to-a-different-destination-directory) that will unzip a group of gzipped files to a different destination directory:

```
dest="unzipped"
for f in *.gz; do
  STEM=$(basename "${f}" .gz)
  unzipped_name="$dest/$STEM"
  echo ''
  echo gunzipping $unzipped_name
  if [[ -e $unzipped_name ]]; then
    echo file exists
  else
    gunzip -c "${f}" > $unzipped_name
    echo done
  fi
done
```